# Checking if power of 2 in Python

Tags: python

How does this Python code check if a number is a power of 2?
`n>0` is pretty straightforward, but what does `(n & (n - 1)) == 0` do?

```py
def is_Power_of_two(n):
    return n > 0 and (n & (n - 1)) == 0
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678333/n-n-1-what-does-this-expression-do

Comment: In the future: if something is a duplicate, please actually vote to close as such.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Sorry about that, I wasn't *entirely* sure (like 94%).  I'll vote to close next time.

Answer (score 0):

Post that provides good explanation:

[What does & mean in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556206/what-does-mean-in-python/42822783)

Below is checking if an integer is odd/even and returning a boolean value

```
(n & (n - 1)) == 0
```

If n = 2, then

```
(n & (n - 1)) == 0
>>> True
```

If n = 7, then

```
(n & (n - 1)) == 0
>>> False
```

The function is_Power_of_two(n) checks if n is greater than 0 **AND** if n is even. If both conditions are met, the function will return **true**.

Answer (score 0):

For integral types '&' computes the logical bitwise AND of its operands.
So lets take n=4.

(4 & (4 - 1)) = 4&3

In binary

```
100 = 4
011 = 3
```

And

```
100 & 011= 000
```

---

The reason this works is because in binary subtracting 1 from any number that is a power of two is just the same number with all of the bits reversed. When you binary AND (&)  these two together you always get a 0.

To elaborate with examples - any number that is power of two is in binary written as a 1 with following 0s. 1,2,4,8,16,... is in binary 1, 10, 100, 1000 and subtracting 1 just gives you a number one smaller than that - 0, 01, 011, 0111 etc.