# Why does True & True give False?

Tags: python, bitwise-operators

```
>>> 5 > 4 & 6 > 5
```

Why does the above expression give `False` in Python, if `5 > 4` is `True` and `6 > 5` is also `True`?

Comment: `&` is the *bitwise AND* operator, it has a higher precedance than the comparison operators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `&` (bitwise "and") has a higher precedence than `>`, so `5 > 4 & 6 > 5` is actually evaluated as `5 > 4 > 5` which is obviously `False`.

[Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) on Python docs.

Comment: `4 & 6 == 1`? My head is spinning.

Comment: @iBug Sorry, should have been `5 > 4 > 5`

Answer (score 1):

In python the `&` operator represents the [bitwise AND operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8556214/13552470), which basically takes the binary form of an integer, and masks the binary form of the first number by the second number.

For example, `10 & 3` returns `2` because the binary form of `10` is `1010`, and with the mask of `3`, we take the last three digits, and find the value of the resulting binary. In this case, it's `010`, which in decimal is `2`.

The operator you're looking for is the literal [`and`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/#boolean-operators) operator!:

```
>>> 5 > 4 and 6 > 5 
True
```

Or better (I believe you already know this):

```
>>> 6 > 5 > 4
True
```

Comment: Given that the question is tagged with "bitwise-operators", I'll take it that OP knows what `&` is in Python. The issue appears to be about the precedence, not the expectation from `&`