# list index out of range despite checking length with "&" operator

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, if-statement

I'm checking length of parameters and if it equals a specific value then it should enter `if`. If not, it should enter into `else`.

```
print(len(sys.argv))
if (
    (len(sys.argv) == 9)
    & (sys.argv[8] == "framework")
):
    employeeId = userid + "frame"
    print("frame")
else:
    employeeId = userid

print("userid")
```

Now passed `len(sys.argv)` is 7 and "userid" should print  but I got the error

> list index out of range

Comment: `&` is bitwise and doesn't short circuit. You need `and`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556206/what-does-mean-in-python/42822783

Comment: You should make that the answer so she can accept it.

Comment: @TimRoberts I've voted to close the question as it's unclear, so I won't be posting an answer. It's unlikely to be helpful to others in future.

Answer (score 1):

The logical "and" operator in Python is `and`, not `&`.

`&` is a bitwise operator which may work similarly for boolean values, but in contrast to `and` it always evaluates both arguments even if the first one is false.

Therefore if `len(sys.argv)` is 7 then `sys.argv[8]` is out of range.

With `and`, `sys.argv[8]` would not be evaluated because the condition `len(argv) == 9` which you have rightfully put in place is false. This property of the `and` operator is called "short-circuiting".

Answer (score -1):

take a look at this:

```
(len(sys.args) == 9)
    & (sys.argv[8] == "framework")
```

you are using `&`, which is bitwise operator, and not a condition `and`

This result this:

```py
1 & sys.argv[8] == "framework"
```

because the first `==` works, and the if couldn't determ if it should be true, it keep checking and running `sys.argv[8]`, which in your case will be invalid

what you are searching for is `and` as:

```
len(sys.args) == 9 and sys.argv[8] == "framework"
```