# Bitwise Arithmetic and Operators

Tags: objective-c, c, math, operators, bit-manipulation

Currently studying bitwise arithmetic. It's really easy, because I have some CS background. But I just don't understand one moment with this operator.

For example:

```
variable3 = variableOne & 3;
```

or

```
variable3 &= 3;
```

Actually this doesn't matter. 

**I don't understand how the process of setting the bits to 0 is going on. And how you can process it on the paper?**

Comment: And I don't understand why people don't search before asking. I guess we must _both_ have something to learn :-) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746613/bitwise-operation-and-usage/1746642#1746642

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let’s say `5&3`, four-bit width:

```
0101b = 5dec
0011b = 3dec
------------
0001b = 1dec
```

You just `&` the bits in the same column. And since the `&` operator only returns `1` when both arguments are `1`, the higher bits from `5` not present in `3` are masked out.

---

As for your example from the comments:

```
$ perl -E 'printf "%b\n", 0x76'
1110110
```

And now:

```
1110110 = 0x76
0000011 = 3dec
-------
0000010 = 2dec
```

…and just to validate:

```
$ perl -E 'say 0x76&3'
2
```

The schema is simple, you just `&` each column:

```
x
y
-
z
```

Where `z` is `x&y`.

---

Aha, judging by your comments in the neighbouring answer the problem is elsewhere. Numeric variables do not contain “hexadecimal values” in them. Numeric variables contain a bit pattern representing a number. “A number” is never binary, decimal or hexadecimal. When you say “three”, there’s no number system in play, three is a three no matter what.

When you say something like `var x = 0x76` in the source code, the machine reads the hexadecimal representation of the number, creates a bit pattern representing this number and stores it in the memory corresponding to the variable. And when you then say something like `x &= 3`, the machine creates a bit pattern representing number three, combines that with the bit pattern stored in the variable and stores the result in the variable.

Comment: Oh.. Yeah.. Thanks. Really easy to understand. So now will practice)))

Comment: FOr example: varibleOne = 0x76; variableOne &= 3; How does it works