# invalid operands to binary ^ (have 'double' and 'double')

Tags: c, operand

I'm rather new to coding and have been building a code to interpolate a cubic spline, but I am stuck on the last equation do the following error:  _"invalid operands to binary ^ (have 'double' and 'double')|"

The problem is in the last bit of the code with "population =" for the two first lines. I would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

```
#include <stdio.h>


main () {

    int x;
    int y;
    double stats[10][2];
    double gpp[8][9] = {0};
    double gppr[10] = {0};
    double year;
    double population;
    int xi = 0;
    year=1950;
    population=0;
    x=0;

    stats[0][0] = 1930; stats[1][0] = 1940; stats[2][0] = 1949;
    stats[3][0] = 1955; stats[4][0] = 1960; stats[5][0] = 1970;
    stats[6][0] = 1980; stats[7][0] = 1990; stats[8][0] = 2000;
    stats[9][0] = 2005;

    stats[0][1] = 21.058; stats[1][1] = 23.547; stats[2][1] = 20.167;
    stats[3][1] = 21.502; stats[4][1] = 24.989; stats[5][1] = 30.852; 
    stats[6][1] = 37.407; stats[7][1] = 43.390; stats[8][1] = 45.985;
    stats[9][1] = 47.041;

    //Initiate  g'' system of equation
    for (x=0;x<8;x++) {
        gpp[x][x] = ((stats[x+1][0]-stats[x][0])+(stats[x+2][0]-stats[x+1][0]))/3;
        if (x<7) {
            gpp[x][x+1] = (stats[x+2][0]-stats[x+1][0])/6;
        }
        if (x>0) {
            gpp[x][x-1] = (stats[x+2][0]-stats[x+1][0])/6;
        }
        gpp[x][8] = ((stats[x+2][1]-stats[x+1][1])/(stats[x+2][0]-stats[x+1][0]))-((stats[x+1][1]-stats[x][1])/(stats[x+1][0]-stats[x][0]));
    }

    //Forward sweep
    for (x=0;x<7;x++) {
        gpp[x+1][x] = 0;
        gpp[x+1][x+1] = gpp[x+1][x+1] - (gpp[x][x+1]/gpp[x][x])*gpp[x+1][x];
        gpp[x+1][8] = gpp[x+1][8] - (gpp[x][x+1]/gpp[x][x])*gpp[x][8];
    }
    //Backward sweep
    gppr[9] = 0;gppr[0] = 0;
    gppr[8] = gpp[7][8]/gpp[7][7];
    for (x=7;x > 0;x=x-1) {
        gppr[x] = (gpp[x][8]-(gppr[x+1]*gpp[x][x+1]))/gpp[x][x];
    }

    //check where is xi
    for (x=0;x<10;x++) {
        if (stats[x][0] > year) {
            xi = x;
            break;
        }
    }

//Calculate population at x
population = (gppr[xi]/6)*((((stats[xi+1][0]-year)^3.0)/(stats[xi+1][0]-stats[xi][0]))-(stats[xi+1][0]-stats[xi][0])*((stats[xi+1][0]-year)))
       + (gppr[xi+1]/6)*((((year-stats[xi][0])^3.0)/(stats[xi+1][0]-stats[xi][0]))-(stats[xi+1][0]-stats[xi][0])*((year-stats[xi+1][0])))
       + (stats[xi][1])*((stats[xi+1][0]-year)/(stats[xi+1][0]-stats[xi][0]))
       + (stats[xi+1][1])*((year-stats[xi][0])/(stats[xi+1][0]-stats[xi][0]));

}
```

I look forward to learning a little more about C!

Hugo

Comment: Looks like you're looking for the `pow()` function in `math.h`.

Comment: C has no exponent operator.  For integer exponents, the `pow` function can be lower performance (depending on the compiler and C library) than doing the exponentiation by hand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`^` is the exclusive-OR operator in C and is unsuitable for doubles. It's a bitwise operator and you can find more details on it (and the other bitwise operators) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746613/bitwise-operation-and-usage/1746642#1746642).

If you want to raise one number to the power of another, you need the `pow()` function.

So something like:

```
((stats[xi+1][0]-year)^3.0)
```

should actually be written:

```
pow (stats[xi+1][0] - year, 3.0)
```

Section `7.12.7.4 The pow functions` of the latest (C11) standard states:

> **Synopsis:**
>   `#include <math.h>`
>   `double pow(double x, double y);`
>   `float powf(float x, float y);`
>   `long double powl(long double x, long double y);`
>
> **Description:**
>   The pow functions compute x raised to the power y. A domain error occurs if x is finite
>   and negative and y is finite and not an integer value. A range error may occur. A domain
>   error may occur if x is zero and y is zero. A domain error or pole error may occur if x is
>   zero and y is less than zero.
>
> The pow functions return x<sup>y</sup>.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I got my solution after implementing this!

Answer (score 3):

C has no exponent operator. `^` is the XOR operator, which doesn't work on non-integers, hence the error. Use the `pow` function instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the last equation you are trying to find the power function of mathematics. but in c "^" this operator means a exclusive or. Better try #include>math.h>