# DBus-Python Network Manager script - WpaFlags issue

Tags: python, dbus

I'm writing a python script in DBus-python for getting some info about available access points through Network Manager. I can correctly get the ssid, mac adress, signal strength values. Although when I try to get the WpaFlags I just get some integers values. I think,I should some how use "NM_802_11_AP_SEC"
but I don't know how. I'll appreciate any advice.

readable results:

```
ssid = ap_prop_iface.Get("org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.AccessPoint","Ssid",byte_arrays=True)
hwaddr = ap_prop_iface.Get("org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.AccessPoint", "HwAddress")
```

Unreadable results:

```
encryption = ap_prop_iface.Get("org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.AccessPoint", "WpaFlags")
```

encryption=0 if there is no encryption -that's ok-
and the other results I get are 324 and 392

Answer (score 1):

WpaFlags (and other *Flags) is an integer composed of bit flags, here [NM_802_11_AP_SEC](http://projects.gnome.org/NetworkManager/developers/api/09/spec.html#type-NM_802_11_AP_SEC). So 324 ix 0x144 (hexadecimal) which is NM_802_11_AP_SEC_KEY_MGMT_PSK | NM_802_11_AP_SEC_GROUP_TKIP | NM_802_11_AP_SEC_PAIR_TKIP.

Here's a SO question  about bit flags in general: [Bitwise operation and usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746613/bitwise-operation-and-usage).

Example:

```
NM_802_11_AP_SEC_PAIR_TKIP = 0x04  // declare other constants too...
flags = 324                        // from an API call really
if flags & NM_802_11_AP_SEC_PAIR_TKIP:
    print "PAIR_TKIP is enabled"
```