# How are bitwise operators being used in this code?

Tags: objective-c, bitwise-operators

I was looking at [PSPDFkit](http://pspdfkit.com/) sample code and saw this:

```
NSDictionary *options = @{kPSPDFProcessorAnnotationTypes :
                               @(PSPDFAnnotationTypeNone & ~PSPDFAnnotationTypeLink)
                         };
```

The constants `PSPDFAnnotationTypeNone` and `PSPDFAnnotationTypeLink` are defined below:

```
// Available keys for options. kPSPDFProcessorAnnotationDict in
// form of pageIndex -> annotations.
// ..
extern NSString *const kPSPDFProcessorAnnotationTypes;

// Annotations defined after the PDF standard.
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, PSPDFAnnotationType) {
    PSPDFAnnotationTypeNone      = 0,
    PSPDFAnnotationTypeLink      = 1 << 1,  // Links and multimedia extensions
    PSPDFAnnotationTypeHighlight = 1 << 2,  // (Highlight, Underline, StrikeOut) - 
    PSPDFAnnotationTypeText      = 1 << 3,  // FreeText
    PSPDFAnnotationTypeInk       = 1 << 4,
    PSPDFAnnotationTypeShape     = 1 << 5,  // Square, Circle
    PSPDFAnnotationTypeLine      = 1 << 6,
    PSPDFAnnotationTypeNote      = 1 << 7,
    PSPDFAnnotationTypeStamp     = 1 << 8,
    PSPDFAnnotationTypeRichMedia = 1 << 10, // Embedded PDF videos
    PSPDFAnnotationTypeScreen    = 1 << 11, // Embedded PDF videos
    PSPDFAnnotationTypeUndefined = 1 << 31, // any annotation whose type not recognized
    PSPDFAnnotationTypeAll       = UINT_MAX
};
```

I understand that `~` is the bitwise not operator and `&` the bitwise and operator, but what is the purpose of their application in this code?

```
NSDictionary *options = @{kPSPDFProcessorAnnotationTypes :
                               @(PSPDFAnnotationTypeNone & ~PSPDFAnnotationTypeLink)
                         };
```

Based on comments below, the above could have been written simply as

```
NSDictionary *options = @{kPSPDFProcessorAnnotationTypes :@(PSPDFAnnotationTypeNone)};
```

Since it is the same as `(0 & ~2) => 0`. What's the point of adding the `& ~PSPDFAnnotationTypeLink` part?

Comment: In the context of this code it seems to be an obfuscated way of getting 0: `(0 & ~2)` => 0

Comment: so what value does writing the extra `& ~2` add? why not just put `0`?

Comment: That I don't know... would vote to reopen were question to focus on why.

Comment: @CarlVeazey cool.. updated the question and voted for it to re-open

Comment: Why is the `enum` skipping 1<<0? Or 1<<9? And why is it using the wrong type for the `All` option?

Comment: John: The 1<<0 is used in more recent versions, 1<<9 has legacy reasons, and what is wrong with UINT_MAX? (Since the enum type is NSUInteger?)

Comment: @steipete: `NSUInteger`'s underlying type is `unsigned long`, and the maximum is `NSUIntegerMax`. An `NSUInteger` will be longer than an `unsigned int` on the desktop or if iOS ever gets 64-bit processors.

Comment: Josh - thanks! Just fixed that in my code.

Comment: @steipete: Oh! I didn't realize this was your code; I thought it was the question poster's. Well, glad I could help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"~" is the bitwise **not**-operator.

As "&" the bitwise **and**.

These are usually used for bitmask (like in your example) or other binary operations (as the name lets suggest). More info on [wiki - Operators in C and C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Bitwise_operators).

They are in no relationship to literals.

Comment: Replace "binary" with "bitwise".

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't know obj-c, only C, but I guess the '&' is 'bitwise AND' and the '~' is bitwise NOT.

Answer (score 0):

It's the bitwise NOT operator (same as many C-based languages), which inverts all bits in the underlying value.

So, for example, the eight bit value `0x57` (binary `0101 0111`) becomes `1010 1000` or `0xa8`.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746613/bitwise-operation-and-usage/1746642#1746642) for a more complete description of the various bitwise operators.