# if (index & 0x88) == 0, how this works?

Tags: c#

Can anyone show me how this operation works? Index is number and it can be any number from 0 to 128. I just don't understand how (index & 0x88) can be 0 or not.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 0x88, when written in binary, is 0b10001000. Therefore, `index & 0x88` is zero precisely when both the 8th and 4th bits of index are 0. Usually this type of condition is used when you are testing for bit-based flags (in this case, the combination of flags indicated by the 8th and 4th flags being unset.)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746613/bitwise-operation-and-usage/1746642#1746642

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The & operator is a bitwise AND, if the binary digits of 0x88 and corresponding spot in index are both 1, it will not == 0.
In the opposite case, if none of the digits are both 1, then the outcome of the & will be 0

In this case, your hex number 88 is 10001000 in binary, so (index & 10001000) can equal to 0 as long as index has 0 in it's 4th and 8th positions (for example, 01110111)

Answer (score 3):

`0x88` is equivalent to `10001000` in binary. Thus, it will be `0` iff the binary value of the index is `0xxx0xxx`, where `x` is any binary digit.

Answer (score 0):

`&` is the `bitwise and` operator (when applied to numbers).

For example, `110 & 101 = 100`

`0x88` is `10001000` in binary.