# Reading bit by bit from a binary file with C

Tags: c, file-io, bit-manipulation, fread

I need to read 256 bit for each step until binary file ends.Is there any operation in c to read bit by bit? I use fread function and read 32 chars. For all chars i shift bit by bit for 8 times. After reading ı write this 256 bits to a file. Do ı have to same thing to write? I mean do ı write 32 chars => 32*8 = 256 bit.

Comment: you can write byte-by-byte. But disk drives are the slowest in computers so you'll want to write a bunch at once to speed up. Small files often aren't a problem but when you're writing a large amount of data then this should be taken into consideration

Answer (score 3):

No, the minimum item you can read or write is a `char` (and keep in mind that's not *necessarily* 8 bits, it depends on the implementation). If you want to manipulate *parts* of a `char` once you have it in memory, you'll need to use the [bitwise operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746613/bitwise-operation-and-usage/1746642#1746642) sich as `&`, `|` `<<` and `>>` (`and`, `or` and `left/right shift`).

And yes, you can do `fwrite` to write an arbitrary number of characters (in the same manner as you use `fread` to read them).

Comment: I have one more question :D I have a 32 char array so it is 256 bits. I need to rotate the left. IF it is 000111 it should be 001110. How can ı do that? Because ı don't have the bits, ı just have char array.