# What does 0fh mean?

Tags: assembly, binary, bitwise-and

I am trying to do

```
and eax, 0fh
```

and I know `0fh` means `15`.
From

```
and eax, 0fh
```

I am supposed to clear all but the last 4 bits of `eax`. I don't understand how you get (32-4)=28 bits of 1 and 4 0s.

Comment: Hint: What's 15 in binary?

Answer (score 5):

15 in binary is `1111` (in facts 15=8+4+2+1); adding the padding zeroes to reach 32 bits (the width of `eax`) we get

```
00000000000000000000000000001111
```

Now, if you do a binary `and` with the content of eax, obviously you clear all the bits of `eax` but the last 4, since the zeroes "kill" whatever digit is in the corresponding position, while the ones let it "survive".

```
  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx AND
  00000000000000000000000000001111
----------------------------------------
  0000000000000000000000000000xxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

You *don't* get 28 1-bits followed by 4 0-bits, it's the other way around. `0fh` is:

```
000...0001111
```

When you `and` something with a 1-bit, you get that something back. When you `and` it with a 0-bit, you always get zero (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746613/bitwise-operation-and-usage/1746642#1746642) for a treatise on the bitwise operators).

`AND`ing a number with `000..001111` will therefore clear all but the rightmost 4 bits.

Answer (score 1):

For brevity, lets look at this instruction instead:

```
and al, 0fh
```

`0fh` translates to `00001111` in binary.

Now regardless of what `x` is in each bit, this is what we get in binary:

```
al  xxxxxxxx
0fh 00001111
------------
and 0000xxxx
```

Concrete example:

```
al  01010101
0fh 00001111
------------
and 00000101
```