# Why do we use >> to get colour values from RGB?

Tags: java, colors

I know that to get colour values from rgb you use

```
b = rgb >> 0
g = rgb >> 8
r = rgb >> 16
```

Could someone explain why this works? Each of those is 8 bits right? Doesn't >> n give the first n bits? How does it work for b and r as well?

Comment: You did already your research about the [shift operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)?

Comment: [this example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_bitwise_operators_examples.htm) might be useful

Comment: `>> n` does not give the first *n* bits. It shifts the number to the right *n* bits. That's why `>>` is called the [*shift* operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html). Incidentally, the first *n* bits can be obtained by `number & ((1 << n) - 1)`, presuming everything fits in all relevant types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually that shouldn't work unless you strip off the unneeded bits at some point.

`>>` is the right shift operator, where zero-bits feed in from the left and bits rolling off the right are sent to the bitbucket (discarded). Consider that a 24-bit RGB value has the following bits, eight per color):

```
rrrrrrrrggggggggbbbbbbbb
```

Right-shifting that by 0 bits gives you the same value, right-shifting it by eight bits gives you `rrrrrrrrgggggggg`, and right-shifting by sixteen bits gives `rrrrrrrr`.

So you can see that the three shifts give you each of the three color values in the "lower" (rightmost) eight bits. A more canonical way to do this would be to `and` it with 255 (`0xff` in hex) to ensure all but the lower eight bits are cleared to zero:

```
b = (rgb      ) & 0xff;
g = (rgb >>  8) & 0xff;
r = (rgb >> 16) & 0xff;
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746613/bitwise-operation-and-usage/1746642#1746642) for a more detailed description of the bitwise operators.

Comment: Is the OP familiar with hexadecimal? For clarification, 0xFF is 255 in hexadecimal.

Comment: Also consider adding types for the variables :)

Comment: tobier, good point, clarified in the answer. Jason, yes, you'd think someone who's been using C-like languages as long as I have wouldn't make a basic mistake like that. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, these are the "Right Shift" operators - so, if the Color number is encoded in 24bits,
being the higher 8 bit for the red color, the middle 8 bit for green and the lower 8 for Blue, something as above might work.

For example, the Orange color encoded as 0xff8000;

doing:

```
rgb = 0xff8000;
b = rgb >> 0; // redundant, the ">>" operator shuld not have been used at all
g = rgb >> 8 ; // g contains ff80
r = rgb >> 16 ; //r contains ff
```

What happens here that it might work with just these operators is that the r,g and b variables are defined as 8 bit unsigned ints, in a way the upper bits (like the g above) get truncated. I don't think that is a good practice, as it will depend on specific 
semantics and correct variable types to hold just 8bit unsigned. The following variant explicitly filters out the higher bits using the bitwise AND operator (&), so that one gets the color components for any size of r, g and b variables, and should be preferred, since it won't cause exactly the doubt that lead you to ask this question:

```
rgb = 0xff8000;
b = rgb & 0xff; 
g = (rgb >> 8) & 0xff ; // g contains 80
r = (rgb >> 16) & 0xff ; //r contains ff
```

Comment: Right, Left - they are all relative to we, dislexic! (fixed now, thanks)

Answer (score 2):

suppose rgb is: 0xFF55FF which in binary is:

```
11111111 01010101 11111111
^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^
    r        g       b     -- rgb color parts (or components)
```

now what your code is doing is extracting each of those components by shifting to right, I assume that r,g,b are of `unsigned char` type (otherwise it would not work):

```
b = rgb >> 0
```

here there is no need to shift, rgb vale is implicitly casted to unsigned char which leaves only 11111111 - b part.

```
g = rgb >> 8
```

here, firstly b part is shifted right so that g part is on its place, and again as above 01010101 binary part is assigned to g, if g is one byte then during assignment it is implicitly casted (r part is casted away) and g is assigned 01010101 binary value.

```
r = rgb >> 16
```

here is the same history as in case of g

Answer (score 1):

You should add the types:

```
int rgb = 0x1234FF;
byte b = rgb >> 0;
byte g = rgb >> 8;
byte r = rgb >> 16;
```

Then it gets a little bit clearer. The bits of rgb get shifted to the right and by assign to a `byte` all beyond the 8th bit get truncated.