# How is this Calculating the Internet Checksum

Tags: python, networking

I've been at this thing for an a few hours trying to figure it out:

```
data = b'\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF'
v = sum(struct.unpack('!%sH' % int(len(data)/2), data))
for i in range(3):
    chksum += v & 0xffff
    v = v >> 16
```

I understand what it's doing until the for i in range part. One part that gets me is this:

```
chksum += v & 0xffff
```

I'm sure v is 8 bytes, and I understand it's basically clearing bits. But it's half the size, so does it do upper or lower?

I don't know. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python numbers are of unspecified bit width - they are of [arbitrary size](https://docs.python.org/3.4/c-api/long.html).

The "bitwise and" operator works as advertised, so let's take it step by step:

1. `v & 0xffff` - masking the least significant 16 bits (because 2^16-1=0xffff) of `v` is truncating `v` to mod 2^16
2. Add the truncated quantity to `chksum`
3. Handle any remaining carry by folding the sum on itself (the Internet Checksum is computed on 16-bit integers)

Your code is incomplete in handling (3), but the idea is the same. For more info, see the [RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1071.txt).

Comment: Well, the return value is chksum ^ 0xffff, so I do think (3) is handled. I think I understand a little better, so when we do chksum += v & 0xffff it really kind of adjust itself to the size of the operand with leading zeros? such as 0x00ffff or 0x0ffff?

Comment: Your questions are answered in the RFC, especially in §4.1

Comment: How is it RFC? That's a Python thing... Let's say v is 0x46325FFFFF and we go v & 0xFFFF. Does it adjust to the size of v with leading 0s or what? Yea, don't point me to RFC when it's not what I'm asking.

Comment: Yes, you said it's truncating, but the question is how? I understand it all now 100% thanks to your answer, but I would like to know how it truncates it.

Comment: If you want to know exactly what bitwise AND means, you could start [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746613/bitwise-operation-and-usage).

Answer (score 0):

The string evaluates to `'!4H'` which happens to be a group of 4 unsigned short values.

Note that `v` without the sum is = `(struct.unpack('!%sH' % int(len(data)/2), data))`
and this is (65535, 65535, 65535, 65535).

Note that 0xffff is 65535.

Unfortunately in Python, this gets converted into an int32 object, and after the `sum` it results in the value: 262140. Within Python, `v.nbytes` is 4, and v.dtype is dtype('int32').

Finally, the `>> 16` right shifts by 16 *bits* not 16 bytes, as in `'%x'%(0xffff >> 1) = '7fff'`