# Operators in sage notebook vs importing from Python

Tags: python, sage

Operators behave differently depending on how I run my sage program.
in the notebook:

```
2^10 
==>1024
```

running my program with `sage -python filename.py`:

```
from sage.all import *
print(2^10)
==> 8
```

What do I have to import in Python to replicate the behaviour of the Sage notebook?

Edit:

Thanks everyone for the basic Python lessons. DSM answered this question
in the comments, turns out sage notebook has a preprocessor.

Comment: `^` is bitwise XOR operator in Python. To power, use `**` operator.: `print(2 ** 10)`, or use `pow` function: `pow(2, 10)`

Comment: Aside: this isn't the only subtle change that the preprocessor makes.  For example, 2/3 will wind up producing a rational in QQ in Sage, but 0 in Python.  It's important to think in terms of Python and not Sage when writing code you intend to import.

Answer (score 2):

In python for `Exponentiation` we use double asterik `**`

```
>>> print (2**10)
1024
```

OR you can use built-in function **pow**.

```
>>> pow(2, 10)
1024
```

***pow***

```
pow(...)
    pow(x, y[, z]) -> number

    With two arguments, equivalent to x**y.  With three arguments,
    equivalent to (x**y) % z, but may be more efficient (e.g. for longs).
enter code here
```

---

`^` is a bitwise operator for performing XOR(`bitwise exclusive or`) operation.

#### *For example*:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [3,4,5]
>>> a^b
>>> set(a)^set(b)
set([1, 2, 4, 5])
```

***[x ^ y](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators)***

```
Does a "bitwise exclusive or". 
Each bit of the output is the same as the corresponding bit in x if that bit in y is 0, 
and it's the complement of the bit in x if that bit in y is 1.

Just remember about that infinite series of 1 bits in a negative number, and these 
should all make sense.
```

- **[You can find great explanation about Bitwise operation over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746613/bitwise-operation-and-usage)**