# How to join hex values

Tags: python

I am reading four bytes from file
I would like to join them

```
g = f.read(60)
f.seek (60)
k60 =f.read(1)
print('byte60',k60)
k61 =f.read(1)
print('byte61',k61)
k62 =f.read(1)
print('byte62',k62)
k63 =f.read(1)
print('byte63',k63)
print(k63,k62,k61,k60)
print (b''.join([k63,k62,k61,k60]))
```

Result is:

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x80'
```

I would like to receive:

```
00000080
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bitwise operation and usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746613/bitwise-operation-and-usage)

Comment: no it is not, I do not want sum them but them next of each other without "\x"

Comment: Give us your input file and the results of `print('byte6x',k6x)`.

Answer (score 0):

You to convert a byte string to its hex representation, you can use the `hexlify()` method from the `binascii` module:

```
>>> from binascii import hexlify
>>> ...
>>> raw = b''.join([k63,k62,k61,k60])
>>> print(hexlify(raw))
b'00000080'
>>> print(hexlify(raw).decode('ascii')  # if you want to convert it to a string
00000080
```

The same could be accomplished by using `codecs.encode(raw, 'hex')`.