# Why the output is giving such value?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

Can anyone explain how this code snippet gives output as 23 instead of 27. I may have less understanding in bitwise operations.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int a = 20, b = 7;
  printf("%d%",a|b);
}
```

Comment: why would it print 27

Comment: `20` is `00010100`, `7` is `00000111`. `|` is ["bitwise or"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR) and it means a bit in the result is `1` if the corresponding bit is `1` for at least one of the operands. `20 | 7` is obviously `00010111` which is `16+7`.

Comment: You can use your windows calculator in "programmer" mode. This will save you from similar questions.

Comment: Why a programmer can't tell between Christmas from Halloween? Because Dec 25 = Oct  31.

Comment: Try `printf("%o",a|b);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to first understand how `or` works at a bit level (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746613/bitwise-operation-and-usage/1746642#1746642) for more detail on the various bitwise operators):

```
0 | 0 = 0
0 | 1 = 1
1 | 0 = 1
1 | 1 = 1
```

Note that last line carefully, `1 | 1` is *not* the same as `1 + 1`.

So, since the result of `or` on multi-bit values just involves doing it on each of the corresponding bits in those values, the expression `a | b` will *only* be equal to `a + b` if the two values share *no* one-bits in common.

For your values, they *do* share a one-bit:

```
              +-shared one-bit--+
              |                 |
              V                 V
    20 = 16 + 4         = 0001 0100
     7 =      4 + 2 + 1 = 0000 0111 
                          ---- ----
20 | 7                  = 0001 0111 = 16 + 4 + 2 + 1 = 23
```

That explains the value that you're getting and why it's not the same as `20 + 7`.

Answer (score 3):

Because in binary 20 is 10100 and 7 is 00111.

So you have:

```
10100
00111 |
-----
10111
```

which is the binary representation for 23, not 27.

PS: `|` is the **bitwise or** operator, so if at least an operand is 1, it gives 1, else 0.