# How to toggle bits

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

Lets say I have a number like 12, which would be represented as 1100, and 5, represented as 0101. What would allow me to get the bits to toggle, as in a function such that 12 (Function) 5 would send back every byte of 5 that is 1 switch the bit of 12 in the same space, receiving 1001?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bitwise operation and usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746613/bitwise-operation-and-usage)

Answer (score 4):

You're talking about an XOR operation (eXclusive-OR) and `^` is the Python operator.

```
>>> bin(12)
'0b1100'
>>> bin(5)
'0b101'
>>> bin(12 ^ 5)
'0b1001'
```