# The python &= operator: what does it mean?

Tags: python, syntax

```
'x&=5'
```

What does it mean when its like this: `x&=3` What does `&=` and what does the `&=` means?

Comment: `&` is bitwise AND. `&=` is bitwise AND + assignment. Equivalent to `x = x & 5`

Comment: I agee with the comment above. This should not be on Stack Overflow. In the future please try to find answers first before posting questions.

Comment: explain step wise with an example for &= operator in python? because i don't understand how did came output by using that operator .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bitwise operation and usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746613/bitwise-operation-and-usage)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `x+=y` == `x = x+y`[*] and same for many other operators.

This means your `x&=5` is the same as `x = x&5`.

So what's `&`? It's a bitwise 'and'. [You can read more about bitwise operators here.](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators)

`&5` basically takes 3rd and 1st lowest bits (because 5 dec == 101 bin) from whatever is your `x`.

---

Notes:

[*] The implementation isn't always the same. `+=` on lists modifies the current list, rather than make a new list with the sum and assign it to the name. But the effect is the same.