# What is the role of “&” when used with integers in python?

Tags: python, list, ampersand

I mistakenly wrote the line of code, I expected it to give me an error but it returned an answer.

```py
Codx = [num for num in range(1,9)     if num & 2 = 0]
Print (codx)
```

I got the answer
[1,4,5,8]

Then I did

```py
Print(3&2)
```

Answer was 2

```py
Print(5&2)
```

Answer was 0

What’s the role of the ampersand?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746613/bitwise-operation-and-usage

Comment: This is a bitwise AND operator. Please consult some Python book/tutorial, operators section. https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

Comment: It's a bitwise AND, not a conditional and, which is what you likely intended. By the way the conditional and in python is simply `and`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the [bitwise-and operator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators): For the official documentation, it does a "bitwise and". Each bit of the output is 1 if the corresponding bit of x AND of y is 1, otherwise it's 0.