# Is bitwise AND distributive over multiplication and what does bitwise AND mean other than normal gate logic

Tags: python-3.x, bitwise-operators, boolean-logic, boolean-operations, boolean-algebra

I am trying to reduce the amount of time taken to implement a fucntion

```py
def findAns(a, b, c):

    return (a&b)*(b&c)
```

What interpretation can I make based on the nature of bitwise AND other than the normal gate based interpretation? What does it actually do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bitwise operation and usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746613/bitwise-operation-and-usage)

Comment: (1) No, it is not distributive. (2) Just that: a bitwise AND - unless your objects are not numbers but classes with redefined `__and__`. (3) If bitwise performance becomes an issue, it may be time to say goodbye to Python and switch to C++/C.