# Why use (bitwise) & when handling keyboard events involving multiple keys?

Tags: python, pygame

Reading [this Pygame question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65127217/can-i-use-this-method-to-not-use-the-bitwise-operator) made me wonder *why*, if I want to check whether the shift key is pressed (simultaneously with another key), I have to write something like

```py
if event.key == K_s:
    if event.mod & KMOD_SHIFT:
        ...
```

and in particular, while I do understand perfectly why this code fragment isn't equivalent to the other one in the question, I am wondering what the reason is for a bit-to-bit comparison, which seems a bit weird in this context, where we're basically just checking if two events occur at the same time.

The value of `mod` *seems* to always be 1 when shift is pressed, and at least at a first glance [the docs](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/pygame/latest/pygame.pdf) seem not to provide any explanation for using `&`.

**Edit**: this has been marked as a duplicate of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746613/bitwise-operation-and-usage) but it obviously isn't, as

- this is specific to pygame
- I had already taken a look and it was not at all as helpful as the answer I got, as the answers mostly deal with the more theorical aspects of the question

Comment: From the second answer to the linked duplicate: *"& is used to test or clear a certain bit"*. In this case it's testing whether the `KMOD_SHIFT` bit(s) are 1 or 0 in `event.mod`.

Comment: @kaya3 yes, I see how the two questions are related, but my question was more about why pygame does things this way than about & per se.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There See [`pygame.key`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html):

> The keyboard also has a list of modifier states (from pygame.localspygame constants) that can be assembled by bitwise-ORing them together.

The modifier states (`KMOD_LSHIFT`, `KMOD_RSHIFT`, `KMOD_LCTRL`, `KMOD_RCTRL`, ...) are represented by a single bit. The states are encoded in `event.mod`. Since several states can be `True` at the same time, several bits of `event.mod` can be set at the same time. Hence, you need to use the binary AND (`&`) operator to mask the bit.

The `KMOD_SHIFT` state is the combination (OR) of the `KMOD_LSHIFT` and `KMOD_RSHIFT` states. This means that `KMOD_SHIFT` is the same as `KMOD_LSHIFT | KMOD_RSHIFT`.

Hence the condition

```py
if event.mod & KMOD_SHIFT:
```

is the same as

```py
if event.mod & (KMOD_LSHIFT | KMOD_RSHIFT):
```

and the same as:

```py
if (event.mod & KMOD_LSHIFT) or (event.mod & KMOD_RSHIFT):
```

Comment: I see! Great answer, now I understand both why it makes sense (which I had already understood thanks to @Carcigenicate's comment) and why it is necessary. Thanks a lot!