# Java Code Explain

Tags: html

I got this code somewhere from the internet

final int time = 80 << 3 + 1;

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Comment: `<<` is the bit shift left operator.  `24 << 8` means take the bits in the number 24, and shift them 8 places to the left.

Comment: Wow Matt Ball i was literally about to post the same link

Comment: tasksBegin[MINUTE_UNIT_NUM - 1] += tasksBegin[0]; means take the integer at index (MINUTE_UNIT_NUM - 1) of taskBegin, add the first element of taskBegin to it and put it back into the index (MINUTE_UNIT_NUM-1) in the array.

Comment: @Flashamo Googling it would have saved many "seconds" of 41 people here, and few minutes of yours !

Comment: @Flashmo 1. [When to use Bitwise Operators ...](http://stackoverflow.com/q/261062/767881), 2. [Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`24 << 8` means shifting the number `24` to the left for 8 bits, which is equivalent to `24 * (2^8) = 6144`.

In the provided code snippet, it encodes a time `hh:mm` into an integer `hh << 8 + mm`.
Since there are 24 hours in one day, the array to represent the activity of every minute in one day requires `(24 << 8) + 1` elements. The `+1` is to make the array index for `24:00` legal.

Comment: The real question is why you would ever put a literal expression in code. You can always precompute them. Maybe in the case of bitshifting it makes the number look less arbitrary. Do you know if literal expressions are computed at compile time or run time?

Comment: Sir can you tell me why is it being used in the code. That would be very helpful

Comment: @FlashmoFlash Please at least provide the usage of the code snippet. Otherwise people can hardly know what it is for, what input it expects, or how it works, not to mention "why `(24 << 8) + 1`."

Comment: We have to calculate the maximum number of overlapped “intervals” at the same time . I have added the interval class.

Comment: @FlashmoFlash The intention is to mix the hour and the minute into one single integer. It uses the lowest 8 bits to store the _minute_ part, and the higher 5 bits for the _hour_ part.

Comment: Sir i would be very much happy if you could explain the same in some more detail.

Comment: @FlashmoFlash Edited answer to explain more. You should figure out how it works by yourself since it's quite straightforward. The only trick was _how to encode a time in date into an integer for array indexing_. Think about how people do the job by _pencil and paper_.

Answer (score 2):

`<<` is a  [left shift operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)

> The signed left shift operator "<<" shifts a bit pattern to the left,
>   and the signed right shift operator ">>" shifts a bit pattern to the
>   right. The bit pattern is given by the left-hand operand, and the
>   number of positions to shift by the right-hand operand.

So `24 << 8` means shift binary value of 24 towards left by 8 bits position.

Follow reference to learn more about it.

Comment: But why is it being used in the code

Comment: Calculate the maximum number of overlapped “intervals” at the same time . I will add the interval class.

Answer (score 0):

It means bit-shift the constant integer value `24` left by 8 bits.